# Eclipse, better classic and add needed plugins or go for a tuned version, like pdt etc.?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I was wondering, is there a big difference between the pre-tuned versions of eclipse, like th pdt and the one for c++ developers and so on?

Or is it absolutely the same, if I take the classic version and add all the plugins I need? I am going for a project, that will have a mix of python, html, css, javascript and php in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, there's no difference between the pre-installed versions of Eclipse and adding all the plug-ins you need to Eclipse classic.

However, the Eclipse "Install New Software" functionality doesn't always work perfectly.

My suggestion would be to download the Eclipse for PHP developers, and add the Python and JavaScript plug-ins.

Once you've determined that the Eclipse plug-ins meet your needs, and before you start your project, zip up your Eclipse and save it.  There are times when your Eclipse gets corrupted, and having a zipped Eclipse with all the plug-ins makes restoration faster.

Comment: Thank you for the "zipping" hint. =)